# Automapper map one field differently

Tags: automapper

I have a class that I want to map to another. All the fields have the same name in both classes, except one.
Is there a quick way to do that, without having to use ForMember for all fields?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution :

```
 cfg.CreateMap<MasterA, MasterB>().ForMember
(dest => dest.IdOld, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```